# Hostname (eg localhost) mean in databases like mysql?

Tags: database

Is it the location of the database. What other values can hostname take, besides localhost ?

Comment: You mean in the user settings? Or for a connection? Your question is not very clear. Judging by the name, I would say it can be any valid hostname `;)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hostname in the context of MySQL refers to either the name of the server hosting the database, or the name of the client computer (trying to) connect to the database, depending on the context.

This link may be a starting point, but you really need to clarify your question. What specific problem are you trying to solve?

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/privilege-system.html

Comment: I wanted to create a new user in mysql. I saw a link - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-users.html

It says - 
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'localhost'
    ->     WITH GRANT OPTION;

In the above lines, what does localhost mean ? Can we have something else, like maybe IP address of a remote server in place of the local host ?

Comment: Yes, you can say 'monty'@'127.0.0.1' or any valid ip address or network that the user will connect from. Use 'monty'@'%' for world-wide access to Monty (don't really do that unless you know what you are doing though).

Comment: yes, the % seems dangerous. Does it mean any computer, anywhere in the world could access the database and maybe even cause harm if it has the password and right privileges ?

Comment: Yes, any computer in the known universe. What kind of access depends on how you have privileges set up (read the link in my answer on the privilege system).